# Putting dynamic strings into an ng-class

Tags: angularjs

I have some code which reads through JSON data, and that data is used to render custom forms. When I render a text input, I want to add validation to the control. This is simple enough but I'm having some trouble working out the correct way to render the validation HTML from the dynamic info.

This is easier to show than explain. So here is my code, and you can see that I'm rendering the properties using the custom data. (e.g. {{fl.fldBasic.fldLabel}} )

```
<div ng-class="{ 'has-error' : editForm.{{fl.fldBasic.fldLabel}}.$invalid && !editForm.{{fl.fldBasic.fldLabel}}.$pristine }">
    <input type="text"
           class="form-control"
           id="{{fl.fldBasic.fldLabel}}"
           tabindex="{{$index}}"
           ng-model="fl.dataValue"
           ng-required="{{fl.fldAttr.attrRequired}}"
           ng-readonly="{{fl.fldAttr.attrReadOnly}}"
           ui-mask="{{fl.edit_Mask}}"
           title="{{fl.fldAttr.attrHelp}}"
           placeholder=""
           required autofocus>
    <div class="help-block"
         ng-messages="editForm.{{fl.fldBasic.fldLabel}}.$error"
         ng-if="editForm.{{fl.fldBasic.fldLabel}}.$touched">
        <p ng-message="required">This field is required</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I run this, this is what is being rendered by the web browser:

```
> <div ng-class="{ 'has-error' : editForm.Label002.$invalid &amp;&amp;
> !editForm.Label002.$pristine }" class="ng-scope">
>     <input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-valid-required ng-touched" id="Label002" tabindex="1"
> ng-model="fl.dataValue" ng-required="true" ng-readonly="false"
> ui-mask="" title="This field contains the last name of the cardholder.
> It can be up to 40 characters long." placeholder=""
> required="required" autofocus="">
>     <!-- ngIf: editForm.{{fl.fldBasic.fldLabel}}.$touched --> </div>
```

If you look, you'll see that the ng-class statement ampersands are being rendered as & amp;'s, and the ng-if at the bottom is rending the data values verbatim.

I've been playing around trying to wrap things in quotes but I just can't find the magic combination that makes it all work. Any thoughts on how to make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using functions instead. Declare a function in your controller that will generate your dynamic string and use that function for `ng-class`. 
That should work.

```
<div ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myHasErrorFunc(editForm, fl.fldBasic.fldLabel)}">
```

And then you should declare the function `myHasErrorFunc` in your scope.

Answer (score 0):

This example works for me:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : adForm.adName.$invalid && !adForm.adName.$pristine }">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{ 'ad_title' | translate }}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="adName" name="adName" ng-model="ad.name" required ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.\!\s]+$/" ng-maxlength="128" />
        <p ng-show="adForm.adName.$error.required && !adForm.adName.$pristine" class="help-block">{{ 'ad_title' | translate }} {{ 'isRequired' | translate }}</p>
        <p ng-show="adForm.adName.$error.maxlength && !adForm.adName.$pristine" class="help-block">{{ 'error.validation.mustBeLessThan' | translate}} 128 {{ 'error.validation.charactersLong' | translate}}</p>
        <p ng-show="adForm.adName.$invalid && !adForm.adName.$pristine" class="help-block">{{ 'Invalid' | translate }} {{ 'ad_title' | translate }} {{ 'error.validation.title' | translate}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group-required"></div>
</div>
```

I'm using bootstrap and I use different `<p>` HTML tags to display the error-messages in the page according to what the error condition is:

- max length
- required
- invalid (regex)